# The wifi driver installer doesn't work in windows 7

Tags: windows-installer

I've just re-installed windows 7 on my lenovo laptop. When I'm trying to install the wireless driver, I keep getting this error message:

`The contents of this file cannot be unpacked. The executable you are attempting to run has been corrupted. Please obtain another copy of the file, verify its integrity and try again.`

I downloaded the driver several times and I'm getting the same file. I also tried to download it from another machine to get the actual file if the network is caching the file but it didn't help too. After a little bit of search, I found out that some people say that it's because of the old windows installer but I could find a newer version for windows 7 to install.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 comes with Windows Installer 5.0, currently the latest version, so I don't think that's your issue.

If you can plug in your laptop via ethernet cable instead, let Windows Update detect and install the correct driver for your WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

It may well be that the file is indeed corrupted from that particular download location. Have you tried downloading it from another source?